# How to add headers in robot framework using WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm new to python and Robot Framework so please don't blame me for questions :)

What I want to do is, add headers to request done by Robot Framework when I'm using WebDriver.

What I have found is that selenium is not supporting adding headers.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to write python script and add it to call Open Browser done by Selenium2Library?
- And how add to request done by Open Browser this script with headers?

Thank You so much for Your help! :)

Comment: What kind of headers? How do you send the headers when you use a browser manually?